# [C]String and Array about %s , %c

Tags: c, string, printf

Why I should use %c here instead of %s? **If i use %s will Error**

```
printf("%c",Array[i]);
```

when I define    `char Array[STRSIZE]="apple"; should use %s here`

so how to use %s and %c correctly?

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
   int main(){
      #define STRSIZE 81

         char Array[STRSIZE];
         printf("Enter a string: ");
         gets(Array);
         printf("\nYou entered: ");
         int i ;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(Array);i++){

         printf("%c",Array[i]);
    }
   return 0 ;}
```

Result:

```
Enter a string: apple
You entered: apple
```

Comment: Check the types!!

Answer (score 6):

`%c` prints a `char`. `%s` prints a string, so it expects a pointer to a `char`.

```
char Array[STRSIZE];
```

Here, `Array` is an array of `char`, so the expression `Array` passed to a function decays to a pointer to `char`. So it can be used for `%s` (assuming the string is valid).

`Array[i]`, however, is not a string. It is a `char`, and as such it can be passed for`%c`, but not for`%s`. So the possibilities are:

- print a string with `printf("%s",Array);`
- print a single char of that string with `printf("%c",Array[i]);`. By iterating through the string you can print the whole string like this, too

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `"%c"` is correct, but don't use `gets`, is no longer part of the standard

You can use `fgets`:

```
char arr[STRSIZE] = {0};
char *ptr;

printf("Enter a string: ");
if (fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin) {
    // skip the trailing new line
    ptr = strchr(arr, '\n');
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        *ptr = '\0';
    }
}
```

to print the string, just use:

```
printf("%s\n", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

the way the second argument passed to `printf` is treated depends on type specified through `%c` or `%s`.
`%c` is used it indicates the char type so the function will read the data from memory location pointed by array[i] that will be of size of char.
where as when you pass `%s` the data type is taken as char array so the function will read the bytes till it gets `\0` from the memory address passed as 2nd argument.
Since you are passing char type variable to `%s` it can lead to run time error since there is a type mismatch.